# query inner join 3 tablas

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy tratando de hacer una consulta con inner join a 3 tablas, pero no hay manera de que me salga... no tengo mucha experiencia con este operador, normalmente uso producto cartesiano o subconsultas, pero ambas cosas requieren más tiempo de procesamiento tengo entendido y por lo tanto estoy centrándome en aprender inner join.

la consulta es la siguiente:

```
SELECT actuacion.tiempoEmpleado as minutosEmpleados, asistencia.fecha as solicitud, actuacion.fecha 
as actuacion, historialbonos.bono as bono
FROM actuacion
INNER JOIN asistencia ON asistencia.codAsistencia = actuacion.asistencia
INNER Join historialbonos ON historialbonos.bono = bonos.codBono
```

Necesito, obtener esos datos y las tablas serían asistencia, actuacion e historial bonos. En historial bonos es donde tengo lo que se ha contratado y la fecha cuando se hizo.

Para que os hagáis una idea, con esta consulta lo que pretendo hacer es un histórico, tal que así

x fecha se contrató un bono
x fecha se realizo una actuación ............. x minutos restantes
x fecha se realizo una actuación ............. x minutos restantes
x fecha se contrató un nuevo bono

Más o menos esa es la idea. Adjunto mi estructura de tablas con los insert.

Gracias de antemano

[image: E/R]

Tablas e insert

**Actuacion**

```
--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `actuacion`
--

CREATE TABLE `actuacion` (
  `codActuacion` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `fecha` datetime NOT NULL,
  `tiempoEmpleado` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `asistencia` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `actuacion`
--

INSERT INTO `actuacion` (`codActuacion`, `fecha`, `tiempoEmpleado`, `asistencia`) VALUES
(1, '2020-11-20 11:45:57', 10, 1);

--
-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `actuacion`
--
ALTER TABLE `actuacion`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`codActuacion`),
  ADD KEY `actuacion_asistencia_foreign` (`asistencia`);
```

**Asistencia**

```
    -- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `asistencia`
--

CREATE TABLE `asistencia` (
  `codAsistencia` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `fecha` datetime NOT NULL,
  `mensaje` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `usuario` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `estado` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'pendiente',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `asistencia`
--

INSERT INTO `asistencia` (`codAsistencia`, `fecha`, `mensaje`, `usuario`, `estado`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(1, '2020-11-20 11:45:42', 'prueba', 2, 'pendiente', NULL, NULL);

--
-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `asistencia`
--
ALTER TABLE `asistencia`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`codAsistencia`),
  ADD KEY `asistencia_usuario_foreign` (`usuario`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de las tablas volcadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `asistencia`
--
ALTER TABLE `asistencia`
  MODIFY `codAsistencia` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=2;

--
-- Restricciones para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `asistencia`
--
ALTER TABLE `asistencia`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `asistencia_usuario_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`usuario`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`);
COMMIT;
```

**bonos**

```
 --
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `bonos`
--

CREATE TABLE `bonos` (
  `codBono` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `tipo` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `minutos` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `precio` double(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `bonos`
--

INSERT INTO `bonos` (`codBono`, `tipo`, `minutos`, `precio`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(1, '1/2H', 30, 20.00, NULL, NULL),
(2, '1H', 60, 40.00, NULL, NULL),
(3, '5H', 300, 175.00, NULL, NULL),
(4, '10H', 600, 330.00, NULL, NULL),
(5, '24H', 1200, 600.00, NULL, NULL);

--
-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `bonos`
--
ALTER TABLE `bonos`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`codBono`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de las tablas volcadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `bonos`
--
ALTER TABLE `bonos`
  MODIFY `codBono` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=6;
COMMIT;
```

**contratan**

```
CREATE TABLE `contratan` (
  `codContrato` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `bono` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `tiempoRestanteBono` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `tiempoSolicitado` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `activo` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `usuario` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `contratan`
--

INSERT INTO `contratan` (`codContrato`, `bono`, `tiempoRestanteBono`, `tiempoSolicitado`, `activo`, `usuario`) VALUES
(1, 1, 30, 0, 1, 1);

--
-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `contratan`
--
ALTER TABLE `contratan`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`codContrato`),
  ADD KEY `contratan_usuario_foreign` (`usuario`),
  ADD KEY `contratan_bono_foreign` (`bono`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de las tablas volcadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `contratan`
--
ALTER TABLE `contratan`
  MODIFY `codContrato` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=2;

--
-- Restricciones para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `contratan`
--
ALTER TABLE `contratan`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `contratan_bono_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`bono`) REFERENCES `bonos` (`codBono`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `contratan_usuario_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`usuario`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`);
COMMIT;
```

**historial bonos**

```
--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `historialbonos`
--

CREATE TABLE `historialbonos` (
  `codHistorial` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `bono` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `usuario` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `fecha` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `historialbonos`
--

INSERT INTO `historialbonos` (`codHistorial`, `bono`, `usuario`, `fecha`) VALUES
(1, 1, 2, '2020-11-20 10:35:58');

--
-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `historialbonos`
--
ALTER TABLE `historialbonos`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`codHistorial`),
  ADD KEY `historialbonos_usuario_foreign` (`usuario`),
  ADD KEY `historialbonos_bono_foreign` (`bono`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de las tablas volcadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `historialbonos`
--
ALTER TABLE `historialbonos`
  MODIFY `codHistorial` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=2;

--
-- Restricciones para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `historialbonos`
--
ALTER TABLE `historialbonos`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `historialbonos_bono_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`bono`) REFERENCES `bonos` (`codBono`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `historialbonos_usuario_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`usuario`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`);
COMMIT;
```

**users**

```
--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `users`
--

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `nif` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email_verified_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `direccion` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `perfil` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'usuario',
  `telefono` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `remember_token` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `users`
--

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `nif`, `nombre`, `email`, `email_verified_at`, `password`, `direccion`, `perfil`, `telefono`, `remember_token`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(1, '45921676z', 'David Serrano Alonso', 'daviserraalonso@gmail.com', NULL, '$2y$10$nZcz5O3MaE/F/ML0QSC7M.1/fe.6QYdd11Faa1Wnsh.E4TiZR3xcW', NULL, 'usuario', 652138927, NULL, '2020-11-20 09:19:46', '2020-11-20 09:19:46'),
(2, '45921676z', 'Admin', 'daviserraalonso@hotmail.com', '2020-11-20 10:29:35', '$2y$10$wxOoOy1hlc8JYnozGKy.ReNwT3Q24akiltSyfrGYJ39wjud72lH7a', NULL, 'tecnico', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

--
-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `users`
--
ALTER TABLE `users`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `users_email_unique` (`email`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de las tablas volcadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `users`
--
ALTER TABLE `users`
  MODIFY `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=3;
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo podrias hacer es ir haciendo inner join hasta llegar a la tabla historialbonos ya que no tenes una relacion directa entre las tablas

```
SELECT actuacion.tiempoEmpleado as minutosEmpleados, asistencia.fecha as 
solicitud, actuacion.fecha 
as actuacion, historialbonos.bono as bono
FROM actuacion
INNER JOIN asistencia ON asistencia.codAsistencia = actuacion.asistencia
INNER JOIN users ON asistencia.usuario = users.id
INNER JOIN historialbonos ON users.id = historialbonos.usuario
```

Comment: Perfecto @francofernandez es justo lo que necesitaba

Comment: Espero te sirva, saludos @scorpions

Comment: Si, me ha funcionado perfectamente!